# Is there any other option to select item from dropdown instead "selectByVisibleText"?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I have the following line of code in my Selenium test which is about selecting item from DropDown:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id='application_id']")).selectByVisibleText("NewApp");
```

Is there any other option to select item from dropdown?

Like CSS selector for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no rule that says you have to use the `Select` class for dealing with a `<select>` element. For example, you could do the following:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id='application_id']"));
WebElement option = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("optionAttribute"));
option.click();
```

Note that you can use this technique to find the option you want using any of the standard `By` methods.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I'm newbie to Java and Selenium so I use Selenium IDE and then edit the script. That is why I thought for dropdown menu only the method I've mentioned above is valid. So, thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - see Select from the [WebDriver API documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/index.html): you can also select by index and value with `selectByIndex(int index)` and `selectByValue(java.lang.String value)`

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id='application_id']"));
element.sendKeys("value_with_you_want_to_select");
```